# Variable initalisation in while loop

Tags: c#, initialization, while-loop

I have a function that reads a file in chunks.

```
public static DataObject ReadNextFile(){ ...}
```

And dataobject looks like this:

```
public DataObject
{
   public string Category { get; set; }

   // And other members ...
}
```

What I want to do is the following basically

```
List<DataObject> dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();

while(ReadNextFile().Category == "category")
{
   dataObjects.Add(^^^^^ the thingy in the while);
}
```

I know it's probably not how it's done, because how do I access the object I've just read.

Comment: are you sure , what you want to ask?

Comment: I having a hard time trying to figure out exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I realize my question is very vague. It's just how do I access the object in the while(ReadNextElement()) :p

Comment: Re the loop logic, is that really what you want to do? Wouldn't you rather read all the "matching" DataObjects from the file, whether there are others in between or not?

Comment: @Timo: Just for the record: am I right in suggesting that your real `DataObject` contains more properties than just the category that you're testing for?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, sorry for the late reply didn't have a chance of logging in last few days. Yeah, you are absolutly right about that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
List<DataObject> dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();

DataObject nextObject;
while((nextObject = ReadNextFile()).Category == "category")
{
   dataObjects.Add(nextObject);
}
```

But I wouldn't do that. I'd write:

```
List<DataObject> dataObject = source.ReadItems()
                                    .TakeWhile(x => x.Category == "Category")
                                    .ToList();
```

where `ReadItems()` was a method returning an `IEnumerable<DataObject>`, reading and yielding one item at a time. You may well want to implement it with an iterator block (`yield return` etc).

This is assuming you really want to stop reading as soon as you find the first object which has a different category. If you actually want to include *all* the matching `DataObject`s, 
change `TakeWhile` to `Where` in the above LINQ query.

(EDIT: Saeed has since deleted his objections to the answer, but I guess I might as well leave the example up...)

EDIT: Proof that this will work, as Saeed doesn't seem to believe me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DataObject
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Test
{

    static int count = 0;

    static DataObject ReadNextFile()
    {
        count++;
        return new DataObject
        {
            Category = count <= 5 ? "yes" : "no",
            Id = count
        };
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        List<DataObject> dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();

        DataObject nextObject;
        while((nextObject = ReadNextFile()).Category == "yes")
        {
            dataObjects.Add(nextObject);
        }

        foreach (DataObject x in dataObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Id, x.Category);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1: yes
2: yes
3: yes
4: yes
5: yes
```

In other words, the list has retained references to the 5 distinct objects which have been returned from `ReadNextFile`.

Comment: Heya, this really seems like the best solution for this. There is however one thing, the file I'm reading from can be exceptionally big (few megabytes). Reading all items upfront, can that be a perfomance issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is subjective, but I hate this pattern (and I fully recognize that I am in the very small minority here). Here is how I do it when I need something like this.

```
var dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();
while(true) {
    DataObject obj = ReadNextFile();
    if(obj.Category != "category") {
        break;
    }
    dataObjects.Add(obj);
}
```

But these days, it is better to say

```
List<DataObject> dataObjects = GetItemsFromFile(path)
                                   .TakeWhile(x => x.Category == "category")
                                   .ToList();
```

Here, of course, `GetItemsFromFile` reads the items from the file pointed to by `path` and returns an `IEnumerable<DataObject>`.

Comment: And Also I have 4 downvoter just one of them said why? and non of them remove it.

Comment: @Sawed: This answer *does* address the question, as well as ordering an alternative (better) approach. Stop being so childish - your answer has been downvoted because it's a bad answer... get over it, and stop downvoting other answers out of spite.

Comment: @Jon skeet, that's your idea. and I just downvoted Jason not others. my answer is not bad, It's an answer. forgot about this. and my name is not like `saw` it's saeed :)

Comment: @Saeed: What do you mean "because it's out of the question?" This is strange behavior, to be sure.

Comment: @Saeed: It's an answer which doesn't answer the question. To my mind, that makes it a bad answer. This answer, however - the one you've downvoted - *does* answer the question. Can you give **any** reason for downvoting it other than because you're annoyed that others have downvoted your answer?

Comment: @Saeed: Apologies for misspelling your name, btw - that was a typo as I was writing the comment on a phone, and it autocorrected it badly :(

Comment: @Jon, @Jason, I just downvoted you because I think the linq is not an answer (is advise) and the first one does not address the `OP`s signature. just this, I didn't downvote @poindexter12 because his upvote is zero, and I personally do not like make someone has -1 score unless the answer is very bad (like p=np or very slow)

Comment: @Saeed: Why is "LINQ not an answer?" What do you mean "the first one does not address the `OP`s signature" (sic).

Comment: first because "(is advise)" you can solve this problem with thousand way like this linq but they aren't answer, second "while(ReadNextFile().Category == "category")" is the signature of `OP` code and `OP` said `how do I access the object I've just read`, And why you want explain what I think? non of your friends which are upvoted you, explain why downvoting me (and may be you). if explaining downvote reason is a rule in site is rule for all not just me.

Comment: @Saeed: The question as written *cannot* be answered while keeping the `while(ReadNextFile().Category == "category")` part (which isn't a signature, by the way). I see you're also *assuming* that upvotes for this answer are due to friendship rather than just agreeing with the answer... and you're also *assuming* that the downvotes cast against you correspond with upvotes for this answer. They do in my case, but you shouldn't assume that's true for others.

Comment: `They do in my case, but you shouldn't assume that's true for others` You think which is difference between you and others? and It's better to let them speak themselves.

Comment: @Saeed: Um, I'm *not* speaking for others, that's the point - whereas you've *assumed* motives for upvoting this answer and downvoting yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<DataObject> dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();
string category = "";

while((category=ReadNextFile().Category) == "category")
{
   dataObjects.Add(new DataObject{Category = category});
}
```

And if you have more complicated object you can do this (like jon):

```
List<DataObject> dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();
var category = new DataObject();

while((category=ReadNextFile()).Category == "category")
{
   dataObjects.Add(category);
}
```

Comment: @Saeed: Sorry, my previous comment apparently didn't make it - I'm on a flaky 3G network connection. This won't compile, because you're trying to add a string to a `List<DataObject>`. The idea isn't to remember the last *category*, it's to remember the last `DataObject`. See my answer for the fixed version.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I'd edited the answer, thanks, I didn't think about the type of list I just want to show the way `OP` wants.

Comment: @Saeed: Still -1, because while all we've been shown is the Category property, in real life I'd expect there to be more data in the object... which gets lost with your current code. As the OP says, he wants to remember *the object he's just read*, not reconstruct it from the one bit of information he's filtering on. It's not hard to do - look at my answer.

Comment: (Also bear in mind that you only left 2 minutes between editing your answer and expecting all downvotes to be removed. I happen to be watching this question, but not everyone will be...) Considering the previous version of your answer wouldn't have compiled, and even now it's not really what was asked for, I'd say that 5 upvotes and 3 downvotes is pretty generous ;)

Comment: No, I got downvote after editing my answer :), and my current answer will exactly addresses current `OP` question.

Comment: @Saeed: No, it doesn't. From the question: *how do I access the object I've just read*. Your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: @Jon skeet, you know better than the `OP` about his question? read first comment above, Also the idea was what I said, It's not good to get four downvote because of syntax or ... , I didn't test it and think about it, I just said the idea, others downvoted me because their answer was joke.

Comment: @Saeed: When the OP commented, the code didn't even compile. But I can read what the OP's question says, as I quoted - and your answer simply *doesn't* cope with that. If the OP really wants to return an object which *only* consists of a string, and then add that same exact string to the list every time, I'd be very surprised... do you *really* think that the real `DataObject` class only consists of a single property? It's interesting how you claim I can't understand the OP's question, but you're psychic enough to know reasons for downvoting an answer which doesn't work...

Comment: (I'd also point out that none of the other answers seem like "jokes" to me. Which ones are you thinking of, exactly?)

Comment: @Saeed:  Down voted this because this solution is hard to read.  Also, nerd fight.

Comment: @Jon skeet, I just can judge about what I can see (DataObject class), In all `OP` after learn this can have any variation on it, I never said you can't understand the `OP`s question, I saing that you can't understand what the `OP` wants better than him,At last non of the others answer addresses near to question.

Comment: @poindexter12, first it's hard for you, second it's a valid answer, third you should downvote Jon's answer by your reason.

Comment: @Saeed:  I find Jon's answer to be more readable with his alternate suggestion, but I agree without it I would have down voted as well.  Also, it is hard for ME to read which is why I down voted it with my down vote.

Comment: @poindexter12, If the answer hard for you is because you are not familiar with this syntax, for example if `OP` wants the answer by `linq` I can downvote someone who answered because i.e linq is hard for me? It's not a good reason, while the answer is valid you shouldn't downvote someone, My linq skill is good enough to answer this by linq, but the `OP` wants to change the value in `while` may be it's not a good practice but it's an answer to question. you can comment is not good practice or add your answer and say why you do it as this but It's not a reason to downvote.

Comment: @Saeed: I suspect the OP misunderstood what your answer was doing. I doubt that he'd have upvoted it if he'd seen that it didn't compile, for example. Now, could you explain in what way your answer addresses the OP's question of "how do I access the object I've just read"?

Comment: @Jon skeet, In first glance, I think `OP` want's to read `Category`, item which is fetched in `while` so it is `how do I access the object I've just read`, so `OP` got the point, you read my answer and others and then left your answer, I answered the question after my browser loads the page :)

Comment: @Saeed: Given that he's got a `List<DataObject>` rather a `List<string>`, that seems an unlikely reading to me. As for the point about when I wrote my answer... are you suggesting that I couldn't have come up with my answer without seeing the others first? How amusing.

Comment: @jon Skeet, No you can write your answer after thinking and judging or without this, but you will get 100+ upvote for every simple answer you provide because you are Jon Skeet, and if i provide your answer after others answer may be I got downvote (or zero point) because I'm not Jon Skeet, and may be I'm a cheater, So now I should get upvote by just online answers or answering hard problems, until my rep becomes good enough, and at last, Jon it is very easy after just seeing some answers(may be wrong) saying better answer, and this is for you not us (under 10000 or 100000 reps)

Comment: @Saeed: If you post a correct answer, you're unlikely to get a downvote. If I post an incorrect answer, I *do* get downvotes - it happens sometimes, and I either delete the answer (if there's already a correct one) or just fix it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet,I talk about other thing but for this question my answer is true, but I got downvote from you and 3 other people (may be has compile error at first but fixed), non of a downvoters have a good logical reason for do not removing downvote, but they didn't. you personally have a reason?

Comment: @Saeed: Yes, I have the reason that I've said throughout: it doesn't answer the question, IMO. The other downvotes may have been cast before the users *saw* the edit, or they may just agree with my analysis of this not answering the question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, It doesn't answer which part of the question?

Comment: @Saeed: The bit which I keep quoting: "how do I access the object I've just read" - i.e. the `DataObject`. You're only retaining the category, not the whole object that's just been read. It's a pretty simple distinction, and I've raised it several times now... I find it hard to believe that you really can't see the difference between your answer and mine, in terms of that specific part of the question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I think you never read my last edit 13 hours ago, If you read I didn't know why downvote I just can say is out of logic, and I can't understand it.

Comment: @Saeed: Indeed, I hadn't seen that edit. Now the useful part of the answer: a) just replicates my answer, b) uses a misleading variable name (the `category` variable doesn't actually represent a category, it represents a `DataObject`), c) creates a `DataObject` for no reason. I've removed the downvote as it's no longer an *actively unhelpful* answer - but equally I don't think it actually adds anything useful compared to what my answer presented ages ago. Personally if this were the other way round (i.e. if I'd had to modify *my* answer and it ended up like someone else's) I'd just delete it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, `a) just replicates my answer` if you want talk in this way, I can say you just copy my way by `assigning value to variable in conditional statement`. this part was the important part of my answer, And I do it before you. how to initializing, and what is good practice, bad practice, .... are not the skeleton of answer.

Comment: @Saeed: I don't understand what you mean - given that the important point was to assign a value to a temporary variable *of the right type* it's hard to see in what way I copied you. I took the OP's general structure and modified it to answer his question. And I believe that giving sensible code in terms of variable names and avoiding pointless assignments is useful in *all* answers. I'm just explaining why I don't think your answer deserves my upvote.

Comment: @Saeed: I should clarify that my point about your answer replicating mine wasn't meant in an "accusing you of *cheating*" sense - just that it's redundant as my answer already provides that suggestion. I frequently delete my own answers if I find that by the time I post them someone else has already posted one which is basically the same.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I think the main part of my answer is `assigning value to variable in conditional statement` (I can't explain it better because of my English) and it's not redundant because I do it before other answers, Yes some times I submit the answer and when page refreshed I will see similar answers exists, So I going to remove it and in my opinion it's not a case.

Comment: @Saeed: If you say so... I still think that assigning the *wrong* value to a variable made your answer effectively useless until your final edit... which was pointless by that time as my own answer had covered it by then. (And I'd still leave my answer up anyway, as I think it's better due to that part of the code being cleaner, and also the suggestion to avoid this awkward loop in the first place. LINQ is a much cleaner solution.)

Comment: 6 years later, its still a poor answer. The first code snippet *DOES NOT DO WHAT OP ASKED*. Indeed, it doesn't do anything that *anyone* is likely to ever want to do. Which makes it a waste of time to try to make sense of this answer. The second code snippet does what is asked, but is poorly written:   (1) the variable `category` is poorly named, as it no longer contains a category.  (2) the variable `category` is initialized to a default DataObject. Why? It does not need to be initialized at all in this case, as it is only used in the loop. If anything, initialize it to null.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into implementing IEnumerator on the class container the call to ReadNextFile().  Then you would always have reference to the current object with IEnumerator.Current, and MoveNext() will return the bool you are looking for to check for advancement.  Something like this:

```
public class ObjectReader : IEnumerator<DataObject>
{
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
       // try to read next file, return false if you can't
       // if you can, set the Current to the returned DataObject
    }

    public DataObject Current
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to go to all the hassle of implementing it yourself - use iterator blocks instead. They rock :)

Comment: I agree you don't NEED to, but if that is the purpose of that object (which it looks like it is), it seems like it's a more elegant solution IMO.

Comment: @poindexter12: Creating a whole type explicitly and then using it is more elegant than just writing a method using an iterator block? I suggest you try writing a complete solution both ways and then judge again...

Comment: @Jon: If you look at what he is asking, and don't try to add anything, yeah, an iterator is the smallest, quickest solution. Based on what he was asking though, it seemed like going through a list of objects and looking at what the current item exactly mirrors the purpose of the IEnumerator, hence the suggestion.

Comment: @poindexter12: If you create an iterator block you can still use the generated `IEnumerator<DataObject>`. The calling code would be the same either way - the iterator block just saves you a lot of hassle. As I say, you should try implementing it both ways...