# How can I use a lambda expression in a while loop condition?

Tags: c#, lambda

```
while(list.next() != null && list.next().asInteger() != 6)
{
 ...
}
```

Is it possible to use an inline lambda function here to avoid calling `list.next()` twice? If `next()` actually removed the element from the list, this would be essential not just convenient.

Comment: Does `list` implement `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Why don't you simply extract a method?

Comment: assuming you were doing something with `list.next()` if that removed it from the list then you wouldn't have access to it in the loop unless you put it in a local var first and if you did that then it becomes easy to write something that doesn't call `next` twice.

Answer (score 4):

```
YourType foo;
while ((foo = list.next()) != null && foo.asInteger() != 6)
{
}
```

Comment: It works but it's not strictly a lambda... this is as much a learning question as a "how should I do this" question - I want to know if the while clause/expression can _be_ a lambda, declared within the while statement itself

Comment: @Mr.Boy It *could* be, but it wouldn't actually accomplish anything productive.  A lambda is nothing more than an anonymous method; there's no need for an additional method here, anonymous or not.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but how I would do that - what the syntax would look like - is the whole point of the question. I think Rawling's answer does this - is that as good as it gets (I see why you wouldn't really want to do it!)

Comment: @Mr.Boy It doesn't really matter.  There's no compelling reason to use a lambda in this situation, so it's really not helpful to learn how one would do it, because one never would.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *for* instead of *while*:

```
for (var item = list.next(); item != null && item.asInteger() !=6; item = list.next()) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variables in while loops. It would be easier to write it like so.

```
WhateverNextReturns nextListItem;
while ((nextListItem = list.next()) != null) && nextListItem.asInteger() != 6)
// Do some stuff
```

Or better yet...

```
WhateverNextReturns nextListItem;
while(true)
{
  nextListItem = list.next();
  if (nextListItem == null || nextListItem == 6)
    break;
  //Do some stuff
}
```

I think using a lambda would make this more complex than what it has to be.

Here's another example in this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431568/variable-initalisation-in-while-loop) of someone assigning a variable in a while expression

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to do this with an inline lambda, but C# *does not like it*:

```
while (((Func<YourType, bool>)(n => n != null && n.asInteger() != 6))(list.next()))
{
    ...                
}
```

Comment: Could you avoid the explicit cast to `Func` by explicitly typing `n` in the lambda? ie `(YourType)n => n != null && n.asInteger() != 6`?

Comment: @Chris No.  The lambda still needs to know what delegate it should be represented as.

Comment: @Chris It's similar to typing `var func = (char c) => c != '6';`. I guess it's because there's no reason for `Func<char, bool>` to be any better than any other delegate that takes `char` and returns `bool`.

Comment: @Servy: Ah, thanks. I've never really used an anonymous lambda like this before so wasn't sure. I figured it could tell the return type so if you told it the input type it might do the right thing. :)

Comment: @Chris There can be any number of different types of delegates with exactly the same signature.  Knowing the signature alone isn't enough.

Comment: @Servy: That makes sense. I was thinking that the fact it was inline meant it didn't matter what the delegate was but I guess that's just not how it works. :) To be honest that code seems unreadable enough that I doubt I'd ever try to do it all in one line like that so I don't need to worry about it. :)

Answer (score -3):

is this list an IEnumerable object? You can always use

```
list.Where(t!=null && t=>t.asInteger()==6).ToList().ForEach(t=>{
//do anything you want with t here.
});
```

Tell me if I got the question wrong.

Comment: what if `list` is not of type `IEnumerable<T>`? `.ForEach` isn't implemented for `IEnumerable<T>`, is it?

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. Your loop loops over all cases matching those criteria, my example stops the moment a list element doesn't match the criteria

Comment: in that case I would fire a TolList() prior to ForEach.

Comment: @Mr.Boy yes I didn't notice that part of problem statement. Sorry.

Comment: It's fine. My answer has been downvoted and you got your answer. Maybe just leave it the way it is. My answer was apparently off conceptually too. So, it doesn't matter.

Comment: That's not really the point, and I haven't accepted an answer - maybe yours is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @stripathi Just because your answer has been downvoted doesn't mean you should stop working.  If you feel you can provide a useful answer, edit your answer and try again.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff The point is that my solution was not really a solution. I did not address the problem correctly and I am not sure about the solution once I understood the problem. I don't really care about downvotes, I am here to try to help and learn in the process.